# I am the inventor but my name was typed in wrong into the online database record

Tags: us20130066839

My name was transcribed in the database record with the town that I live in as my last name instead of my actual last name.

How is this type of error at the USPTO fixed ?

Comment: Hi, AskPatents is an online service in Q&A format where users help find **prior art** on **US Patent Applications** and ask questions about the US Patent process. Ask Patents is not able to correct assignment information with the USPTO. Please see [faq] for more information about which topics are on topic for Ask Patents and feel free to resubmit. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: I am voting to reopen to answer it as a question about how the USPTO patent system works (the bureaucratic mechanics).

Comment: As Micah says, Ask Patents has no pipeline to the bureaucracy of the patent office. If this is reopened I will post a real answer but don't worry this was a USPTO mistake typing in data and can be very easily fixed by the law firm the you are using.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like (from the [USPTO Public PAIR](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) database) the USPTO made a mistake re-typing information from the ad hoc Application Data Sheet the attorneys used. It is correct on the ADS. Most people now use the "live" PDF form the USPTO provides. With that form the data goes in via XML, untouched by human hands.

Your (very big name firm) attorneys need to point out the error made by the USPTO to them in writing and request a new, updated filing receipt.

This is not a recordation issue. Recordations are kept track of separately by a different corner of the USPTO. The record doesn't show any assignment recorded with then so far but I imagine you have already signed it all over to Carbonate since they are the applicant for all countries except the U.S. in the PCT application.